# Error #2030: End of file was encountered?

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, actionscript, arrays, runtime-error

I'm having this problem when i want to send using socket a message...

```
textField.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,enterHandler);

  function enterHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER ){
            socket.writeUTF(textField.text);
            socket.flush();
            trace(textField.text); //the output is what input text is, so the input field is right
        }
    }
```

The error is this :
        Error: Error #2030: End of file was encountered.
    at flash.utils::ByteArray/readUnsignedByte()
    at socket_fla::MainTimeline/closeListener()

Any Idea?

Edit:
After checking the Java server (RedDwarf) that the client is connected to, it shows that the Message is received, then SEVERE: unknown opcode 0x61
Tried googling it, nothing..

Comment: The error has nothing related to the posted code. There error is telling me you have an open brace "{" somewhere without the corresponding closing brace "}"

Comment: Not really, i double checked... This error is shown after I compile the  code, when i press enter in the input field..

Comment: Ah its end of file on the data set. lol I misread it. I am not familiar with red dwarf but I get the feeling that when the data is sent it is not adding a null character at the end. the error states it is in closeListener which you did not post. also try putting socket.writeByte(0); before you flush.

Comment: here it is :
`function closeListener (e:Event):void {
      buffer.position = buffer.length - 1;
      var lastByte:int = buffer.readUnsignedByte();
      if (lastByte != main.EOT) {
        return;
      }
      
      buffer.length = buffer.length - 1;
      
      loader = new Loader();
      
      loader.loadBytes(buffer);
  
      loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, 
                                                assetInitListener);
    }

     function assetInitListener (e:Event):void {
      addChild(loader.content);
      out("Asset initialzed.");
    }`

Answer (score 0):

this question may be caused when you haven't addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, data) on the socket in the server. you must read data after you have already got it.